# ES6 object dies

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm checking new ES6 `cool things`, and now I am learning new classes definitions.

All is clear, `class`, `extends`, `constructor`, etc.

Example:

```
class AnimalES6 {
    constructor(name) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
}

var animal = new AnimalES6('Tiger');

console.log(animal.name); // Tiger
```

But what about `destruct`?

Can I call some function, when object dies, like in PHP/JAVA?

```
animal = null; // "Now" (but not in this moment =) ) destruct() method must be called
```

Comment: Javascript don't have destructors but the object will be garbage collected.